How can we request audio pronunciations?
Stack Exchange doesn't feature Soundcloud or audio. No offense, but Stack Exchange takes long time to add new features! Can we ask users to upload audio to websites like forvo.com?
For example, I want hear correct pronunciation of 頗 - Wiktionary

Cantonese (Jyutping): po2, po1

蛻 - Wiktionary

Cantonese (Jyutping): seoi3, teoi3


for cantonese pronunciation, the multi-function chinese character database (漢語多功能字庫) suits your need.
頗:
http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=頗
choose a romanisation scheme on the left pane (the bottom one, marked “cant. scheme:”)
click the “sound symbol” in “canton. syllables”.
or, the direct links of the sound files:
http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/po1.Mp3
http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/po2.Mp3
have fun :)

This topic has been brought up a few times here.  I'm not completely up-to-date on what's possible, but I understand SoundCloud and YouTube (e.g. Music.SE, Gaming.SE) are possible at some sites.  One user even gave a workaround via code snippets.  However, we can't use any of these currently.
For site-specific changes that are not straightforward to implement, Stack Exchange can indeed take a long time.  I guess they have to be careful: there's legal issues, performance issues, along with many features interacting with each other, and we're accustomed to a high quality of service.  In the meantime, we're can use off-site services for audio hosting, and link to them.
If you want to ask for audio pronunciations to be uploaded at external sites, I don't see a problem with that, as long as the question is otherwise reasonable enough.  (Although, I'm far too shy to put my awful voice on here, and maybe others feel likewise.)  Indeed forvo.com seems reasonable, and (I am not a lawyer) the license seems compatible:

The user retains all rights to the pronunciations and translations that they upload, share or publish to their profile, ... In the same manner, the user can use the pronunciations and translations made available in Forvo Media S.L. in any way as long as they are not used for commercial purposes.

However, it's not the only option.
In addition, there are a few resources around on the Internet which might be useful for searching pronunciations, in particular YouGlish searches YouTube subtitles, and ChinesePod searches their podcasts.  There are sites like Shtooka which give audio pronunciation according to pinyin.

PS. The topic of embedded audio was most recently raised here: Embedding sound clips in posts using Soundcloud
